# Expanding a row in a UITableView

Tags: ios, ios4

I would like to "expand" a row in a UITableView just like the build in iPhone Mail does when you click on the "Cc/Bcc, From:" row/field, so that one row gets replaced with three new rows.

I have tried just changing my model and calling [tableView reloadData] in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, but that does not work, and also I would prefer that it would be animated.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`. It will let you set an animation for the changing of the rows. In an app I wrote, I changed the size of the table view cell and then reload just that cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if( selectedPath == indexPath)
{
    return;
}

showNutritionInfo = NO;

NSIndexPath *oldSelectedPath = selectedPath;
selectedPath = indexPath;
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, oldSelectedPath,nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; }
```